# jQuery plugn similar to USA TODAY's article photos?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on building a news website (was asked to come up with the design for a new product) and decided to use the opportunity as a chance to teach myself more about JavaScript. My knowledge in this department is basic, but I've been experimenting with jQuery plugins by deconstructing them and learning as much as I can. That being said, I hope this isn't a dumb question or something I'm just overlooking.

--

I'm looking to implement [the same basic function USA TODAY has on its article photos](http://www.usatoday.com/story/theoval/2013/08/12/biden-harkin-steak-fry-iowa-2016/2642113/), which takes the thumbnail photo and resizes/expands the image on click. After spending some time searching for jQuery plugins, the only thing I found close to it was jQuery.popeye, which is a good start, but not exactly what I want. For starters, popeye doesn't resize the image, it starts with one file and after the div expands, it links to a new, larger image. Also, the way popeye is built, the image container is static and requires fixed heights — not ideal for a news environment.

But I went ahead and added it to my test site so I could try to break it apart and see if I could easily rebuild it according to my needs. [Here's what I have](http://chrislusk.me/lbregister/story.php).

Rather than trying to debug what I've done, I'm just asking if anyone knows if there are better plugins out there? What core functions I could learn to try and build it on my own? Or if anyone knows what USA TODAY uses?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Here's a link for more info about [jQuery.popeye](http://dev.herr-schuessler.de/jquery/popeye/index.html). Don't have enough clout to post more than two links yet! Thanks again.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: It is better to use multiple, different resolution, images. This reduces bandwidth and speed up initial loading. Why do you want to use one image (presumably hires) for the thumbnail image?

Comment: @Liam, thanks for the tip. Since I'm primarily interested in learning about what USA TODAY is using or what else is out there to discover, I'll look elsewhere for help. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Good point, @HiTechMagic. I suppose I'm looking to use one image for the user's experience. Even though it's brief, I don't like the image disappearing as it switches from the thumbnail to the larger version. Besides, the size difference between the two isn't that large (from 200px to 620px). Do you think it has that large of an affect on the initial load?

Comment: the effect on the load will be the sum of the images. I would say 2 images would give you **worse** performance than one big one. 1 image of 1K is going to be more efficient overall than one small image of 0.5k and one large one of 1K. Plus you can only maintain 2 http channels in any single web request.

Comment: @Liam: Yes, that *is* valid for 1 image where only 1 image is then enlarged. chrismlusk: If the selected image can be predicted it can be pre-loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without recommending a tool to do this, you could do the same thing yourself without too much effort.

If you inspect what they are actually doing there it's pretty simple, the image is full size (big version) and they are just resizing the div.

so:

```
<aside itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject" 
    class="single-photo expandable-collapsed" style="width: 180px;">
</aside>
```

is simply [animated](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to:

```
<aside itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject" 
        class="single-photo expandable-collapsed" style="width: 540px;">
 </aside>
```

notice the width property changing.

so the javascript would be something simple like:

```
$('#clickelement').click(function() {
    $('picture').animate({
    width: 500
  }, 5000);
});
```

And a similar function to resize it small again.

Comment: Thank you, @Liam. I'm too green to upvote your answer, but this is definitely useful and a nudge down the right path. Glad to see it isn't complicated. I'll try this out. Thanks!